# Emacs 25.1 ibuffer. "Query replace in each of the marked buffers" issue

Tags: emacs

I want change text in multiple buffers, to do this:

```
M-x ibuffer 
'Q' (Query replace in each of the marked buffers)
‘Y’ (To replace all remaining matches in all remaining buffers with no more questions)
```

The problem is that 'Y' behavior
seems to be equal to 'y' behavior. It changes just the item at point and jumps to the next.

Please, what can I do to let 'Y' working?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't get an answer, you may not be missing anything and it may be a bug. In that case, `M-x report-emacs-bug`.